# in mysql geting top 5 recodes the data in json format

Tags: mysql, json

in a mysql table the data in json format to get top 5 records without knowing the key .to filter total  json data and retrive top 5 records .in json data there are no of keys. based upon key we retriving the top 5  records

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.